# Problem arise displaying table caption

Tags: tables

I am facing and issue regarding table caption.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}   


 \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Comparison between \ce{H2o} activity coefficients for the following starting conditions: n_{\ce{NH3}}=3 mole, n_{\ce{H2O}}=34.4 mole; T=57\celsius}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \toprule
        Something & Something & Something & Something \\
        \midrule
        number & number & number & number \\
        number  & number & number & number \\
        number   & number & number & number \\
        number  & number & number &  number \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

I don't understand why the table caption doesn't appear...thank you very much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've edited the lines of LaTeX code by four spaces so that they are automatically pretty-printed by the site's software. Please indicate which document class you use, which packages you load to typeset stuff like "\ce{H2o}", and if you use a caption-related package such as `caption`. Ideally, you would edit your posting to create an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Comment: Hi guys, I edited the code.

Comment: What, precisely, is the issue: That the caption isn't centered, or that it doesn't show up at all?

Comment: It doesn't show up at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things like `n_{\ce{NH3}}` require math mode (`$...$`). Also I suggest you to use `siunitx` facilities to typeset  number with units.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison between \ce{H2O} activity coefficients for the following starting conditions: $n_{\ce{NH3}}=\SI{3}{\mole}$, $n_{\ce{H2O}}=\SI{34.4}{\mole}$; $T=\SI{57}{\celsius}$}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    Something & Something & Something & Something \\
    \midrule
    number & number & number & number \\
    number  & number & number & number \\
    number   & number & number & number \\
    number  & number & number &  number \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the log file would certainly have shown an error in the input line for the caption.